# Resilience4j CircuitBreaker resultRecord problem

Tags: circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I'm using resilience4j circuit breaker module. I can break the circuit when throw an exception. That's OK. But I also need to check HttpResponse message. I couldn't find how to use **recordResult** function. Is there anyone success to use it?

```
public class CircuitBreakerHelper {
    public CircuitBreaker createCircuitBreaker() {
        // Create a custom configuration for a CircuitBreaker
        CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .failureRateThreshold(50)
                .slowCallRateThreshold(50)
                .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(3)
                .minimumNumberOfCalls(2)
                .slidingWindowType(CircuitBreakerConfig.SlidingWindowType.COUNT_BASED)
                .slidingWindowSize(2)
                .recordExceptions(Exception.class)
                //.recordResult(result -> result.equals("etc")) 
                .build();

        CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry =
                CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(circuitBreakerConfig);
        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerRegistry
                .circuitBreaker("name");
        return circuitBreaker;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below change in response entity and Like i only used String you can use any type or parameterized type

```
Supplier<ResponseEntity<String>> decoratedSupplier = CircuitBreaker
            .decorateSupplier(circuitBreaker, this::getStringResponseEntity);

    ResponseEntity<String> result = Try.ofSupplier(decoratedSupplier).get();

private ResponseEntity<String> getStringResponseEntity() {
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity=  restTemplate.postForEntity("PROTOCOL://HOST:PORT/API CALL",null,String.class, (Object) null);
    return responseEntity;
}
```